# MultiTenant Azure AppRegistration with Server Side Blazor

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using the default Blazor Server Template in Visual Studio 2022 with the authentication set to use the Microsoft Identity Platform.

I have an AppRegistration in my Azure Active Directory account set to allow accounts in any organization (Multitenant):

[image]

In my **appsettings.json** file I am using the correct client & tenant id:

[image]

When I run the application I can log in with any account that is in my AAD tenant (or has been invited into my AAD). However when I try to use an identity from another AAD Tenant I get the following error:

> Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'TENANT NAME' and cannot access the application 'APP-REGISTRATION-ID' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.

From what I have found in the docs and other articles I need to be using the common endpoint for logging in, but if I change the **"Domain"** in my appsettings to **"common"** it does not make a difference and if I update **"Instance"** to **https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize** or **https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/** I get an exception as the URL is not correct.

Perhaps the default Blazor Server Template is set to use Single Tenant app registrations? How can I have it properly use Multitenant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the selected supported account type, you have to change the ***value*** of **`TenantId`** in **appsettings.json** file.

- For ***Single-Tenant*** account type, it should be "**`your_tenant_id`**"
- For ***Multitenant*** account type, it should be "**`organizations`**"
- For ***Multitenant and personal Microsoft accounts*** type, it should be "**`common`**"

As you have selected **"Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)"**, please check by changing your **appsettings.json** values like below:

Your **`TenantId`** value must be **organizations** and your **`ClientId`** value must be **your_application_id**.

[image]

Please check your **`Domain`** value. You can find your **domain** here in your ***Azure AD overview*** page:

[image]

Make sure to include **`CallbackPath`** from your **appsettings.json** file in ***Redirect URI*** of your application to avoid **redirect URI mismatch** error.

Please find below references if they are helpful.

**References:**
[Ref1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/web-app-quickstart?pivots=devlang-aspnet-core#step-3-configure-your-aspnet-core-project), [Ref2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist), [Ref3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#authority)

Comment: That was it! I had thought it was the Domain I needed to change but it didn't occur to me that it was actually the TenantId.